# Angular runs the controller multiple times

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js

I am currently developing a chat web app. This should be realized as a single page app. For this I use Angular Router. I use socket-io to send the messages from the client to the server. Navigating between the routes actually works quite well.

In the route `home.html`, there is an input element for entering the message. After clicking the button, it will be added as an `<li>` element in the `<ul>` list and displayed. When starting the app, I can write messages normally. But if I navigate from the home route to another route and then go back to home and enter the message, it will be sent twice. The next time you navigate back and forth then three times, and so on. As if the controller is running several times.

I cannot find a solution to this problem on the internet. But that has to go anyway.

P.S: I have only included a script file in `index.html`, because I use gulp to put all the js files together in one file.

Here is the code.

**`index.html`**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <base href="/">
    <title>FB4 Messenger</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=xo, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/style.css">
</head>
<body ng-app="chatApp">
    <div class="loader">
        <div class="loader-text">Laden...</div>
        <div class="progress">
            <div class="progress-bar progress-bar-danger progress-bar-striped active" role="progressbar" style="width: 100%"></div>
        </div>
        <!--progress-->
    </div>
    <!--loader-->
    <header>
        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data- toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <section class="layout">
                        <div class="branding">
                            <a href="/">
                                <img src="images/header/app_fh_logo.png" alt="App logo">
                            </a>
                        </div>
                        <!--branding-->
                    </section>
                    <!--layout-->
                </div>
                <!--navbar-header-->
            </div>
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="active">
                        <a href="/">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-home"></span>
                            Startseite
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/profile">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span>
                            Konto
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="/about">
                            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-info-sign"></span>
                            Über
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- navbar collapse -->
        </nav>
    </header>
    <!--header-->
    <!-- ANGULAR DYNAMIC CONTENT -->
    <div ng-view></div>
    <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

**`home.html`**

```
<div class="container">
    <ul id="messages"></ul>
    <div>
        <input id="m" ng-model="message" autocomplete="off" />
        <button id="send" ng-click="send()">Send</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

**`about.html`**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card">
        <img class="card-img-top" src="../images/header/app_fh_logo.png" alt="Card image cap">
        <div class="card-body">
            <h3 class="card-title">FB4 Messenger</h3>
            <p class="card-text">Version: 0.0.1 </br> &#9400; </p>
            <a href="/" class="btn btn-primary">Startseite</a>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**`app.js`**

```
let $ = jQuery = require("jquery");
require("./bootstrap.min");
require("angular");
require("angular-route");

angular.module("chatApp", ["ngRoute", "appRoutes", "MainCtrl", "ProfileCtrl", "AboutCtrl"]);

$(function() {
    $(".loader").fadeOut(1000);
});
```

**`appRoutes.js`**

```
angular.module("appRoutes", []).config(["$routeProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function($routeProvider, $locationProvider) {
        $routeProvider
        .when("/", {
            templateUrl: "views/home.html",
            controller: "MainController"
        })
        .when("/profile", {
            templateUrl: "views/profile.html",
            //controller: "ProfileController"
        })
        .when("/about", {
            templateUrl: "views/about.html",
            //controller: "AboutController"
        });
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

**`mainCtrl.js`** (here the message is sent to the server)

```
angular.module("MainCtrl", []).controller("MainController", ["$scope",
    function ($scope) {
        let io = require("socket.io-client");
        let socket = io.connect();

        $scope.send = function () {
            socket.emit("message", $scope.message);
            $scope.message = "";
        };

        $("body").keypress(function (event) {
            if (event.keyCode === 13) {
                $("#send").click();
            }
        });

        socket.on("message", function (m) {
            let $li = $("<li>").text(m);
            $("#messages").append($li);
        });
    }
]);
```

And the Server, **`index.js`** that receives the messages

```
const express = require("express");
const http = require("http");

let app = express(); 
let server = http.createServer(app);

app.use(express.static(__dirname + "/"));
app.get("*", function (req, res){
    res.sendFile(__dirname+"/index.html");
});

let io= require("socket.io")(server);
io.on("connection", function (socket) {
    socket.on("message", function (m) {
        io.emit("message", m);
        console.log(m);
    });
});

server.listen(3000, function () {
    console.log("Server runing");
});
```

Comment: Have you used console.log to verify if the controller is running more than you expect? Seems like you could narrow down the problem some if you can see what's running when.

Comment: I used console.log in the controller and got 2 times the same output. But only after I chose a different route and then went back to / home and entered a message

Answer (score 1):

This is problem.

```js
$("body").keypress(function (event) {
    if (event.keyCode === 13) {
        $("#send").click();
    }
});
```

Everytime your controller loads this is attached to the body as a new function. So it triggers everytime the same function call.

I suggest you could use this

```js
  $("body").removeAttr("keypress");
  $("body").keypress(function (event) {
        if (event.keyCode === 13) {
            $("#send").click();
        }
    });
```

Better yet, use ng-click/ng-keyup and provide a function in scope

```js
    // home.html
    ng-keyup="$event.keyCode == 13 && vm.sendFn()"


   // in controller 
   vm.sendFn=function(){
     ... code ...for ..send
   }
```

**Edited**
Can you change MainController this way and try. 
It probably happens because of something similar to this -
https://github.com/angular-fullstack/generator-angular-fullstack/issues/490

```js
let io = require("socket.io-client");
 let socket = io.connect();
 socket.on("message", function (m) {
    let $li = $("<li>").text(m);
    $("#messages").append($li);
 });

angular.module("MainCtrl", []).controller("MainController", ["$scope",
    function ($scope) {
       
        $scope.send = function () {
            socket.emit("message", $scope.message);
            $scope.message = "";
        };

    }
]);
```

Comment: I just tried it without  $("body").keypress(function (event), but after navigating from and to home, I still get several messages displayed.

Comment: Can you put your changes here? I wonder how it would trigger when the function is not available

Comment: angular.module("MainCtrl", []).controller("MainController", ["$scope", function ($scope) {

    let io = require("socket.io-client");
    let socket = io.connect();
    
    console.log("Here");
    
    $scope.send = function () {
        socket.emit("message", $scope.message);
        $scope.message = "";
    };
    socket.on("message", function (m) {
        let $li = $("<li>").text(m);
        $("#messages").append($li);
    });
}]);

Comment: Sorry i'm new here. I dont know how to edit comment like a code

Comment: It is ok. I think socket is also registering your function in global scope. Remove the subscription with this 
   socket.removeAllListeners("message");
   // before 
   socket.on("message", function (m) {
            let $li = $("<li>").text(m);
            $("#messages").append($li);
        });

Comment: no luck. Still the same issue. after navigate 3 times to other route and back i see the output in the console "3 here"

Comment: YYYYEEESSS. Everything works now, as I wish. I am very grateful! Without you I would not have solved that! Thanks alot.